# How to avoid repeated data structures in Code First?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I find myself with a whole lot of classes representing lookup tables, such as JobTitle and Language, that all share the same structure, i.e.

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

How can I avoid repeating this structure, without introducing an extra property, e.g. a complex type of IdName, with the same structure as above, e.g.

```
public class Gender
{
    public IdName Inner { get; set  }
}
```

I want to avoid having to reference Gender.Inner.Name and instead refer just to Gender.Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case create a base class containing `Id` and `Name`.

```
public class BaseEntity 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

and your `Gender` will become:

```
public class Gender : BaseEntity
{
    ...
}
```

To avoid mapped inheritance which you don't want always follow these rules:

- `OnModelCreating` doesn't map `BaseEntity` - only derived classes are mapped
- Your context doesn't contain `DbSet` for `BaseEntity`, only for derived types
- You don't nave `EntityTypeConfiguration` registered for `BaseEntity`

If you follow these rules the inheritance will be only in your application, not in your database.

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav. It never even occurred to me that inheritance could be kept inside the app only.